# What are the cases Access point disconnect station without sending disassociation or deauthetication to station?

Tags: wifi

What are the cases Access point disconnect station without sending disassociation or deauthentication to station?

Comment: What exactly are you asking?

Comment: AP initiate disconnect, but its not sending disassoc or deauth frame to station.what are the possible reasons could be? Except frames missing in air.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it would be pretty strange...the AP is *meant* to send a disassociation to any connected station. The only possibility that springs to mind is failing to find "clear air" while sending the disassociation.

I.e. AP decides to disassociate a station. The MAC layer receives the request to disassoc the station, and puts it in a queue. Every time the AP attempts to send the disassoc frame there is something else sending, and the AP does not pass the collision avoidance check. Eventually the request in the MAC layer times out.